# loading data from azure mobile service into xamarin forms app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, f#, azure-mobile-services, c#-to-f#

i am having an issue with code written in F# for xamarin forms app. I added azure mobile service to my app as the backend and also enabled offline sync feature. I am able to add records into the backend but having a huge problem loading the data from the backend. Any help with this will be so much appreciated.

```
type Backend() =
    let client = new MobileServiceClient("link to the azure table here")
    let mutable table = Unchecked.defaultof<IMobileServiceSyncTable<Items>>
member x.Initialize()=
    let path = Path.Combine(MobileServiceClient.DefaultDatabasePath,"local.db")
    let localstore = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path)
    do localstore.DefineTable<Items>()
    do client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(localstore) |>Async.AwaitTask|>ignore
    do table <- client.GetSyncTable<Items>()
member x.SyncTable()
    async {
       do client.SyncContext.PushAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.ignore
       do table.PullAsync("query", table.CreateQuery()) |> Async.AwaitTask |> ignore
    }
member x.GetTable() =
    async {
       do x.SyncTable() |> Async.RunSynchronously()
       let! result = table.ToEnumerable() |> Async.AwaitTask
       return new ObservableCollection<Item>(result)
    }
```

when i run the app and the GetTable method is called, the application stops at the third line of the method. Nothing else works further than that point. It seems more like a dead pool. i think its a runtime error. Any help with this will be appreciated....... 
Note: An instance is of the Backend class is created and the Initialize method is been called prior to calling the GetTable method......

Comment: mmmmm, not 100% sure, but it seems you don't need to use Async.AwaitTask, you're using async incorrectly